# Generate a .log file plsql / oracle

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

What i want do, is to generate a .log file that describes all my error, start time, end time, and so one. I found a way to have something like that but not in corect way.

I want to generate that file automaticaly, without being required to define it manually.
From what i have  understood, is that UTL_FILE.FOPEN, when is not found that file, create one.

My app. is working. The question is, HOW TO GENERATE A FILE IN PLSQL (.log file) without create it manually.

```
create or replace procedure read_files(input varchar2) as  
  begin
  declare

F2 UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
F2 := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('FOLDER',input||'.log','w');
UTL_FILE.put_line(F2,'Start processing file at : ' || systimestamp);
UTL_FILE.put_line(F2,'End processing file at :'||systimestamp);  
 -- Close file  
UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(F2); 
END; --end begin
```

Comment: "begin" should come after F2 variable declaration. Also errors and auxalarm are not defined.

Comment: I know, that ! But I am asking in a general way. How to generate  a file in plsql/ oracle. My app. is working but is lose of time to create manually that file of log.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Since you already have a database, the usual way is to store this information in a database table - much easier to query, filter etc.

Comment: Because so I was asked to do. I found the probleme ! Where I stored my files, I had no right to create files / folders. THANKS all !

Comment: Please add the last comment as an answer so that others know the question is answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the probleme ! Where I stored my files, I had no right to create files / folders. THANKS all !